# How can i make a calculator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was trying to make a calculator in ruby a very simple one because i am new to the language and i barely know any code but when i run this it is asking me for the variable then does Enter First Value instead of asking first. How can i fix it.

```
while true do

x = gets.chomp
  puts "Enter First Value:" , x 
  
op = gets.chomp
  puts "Enter Operator" , op

y = gets.chomp
  puts "Third value" , y
 
z = eval( x + op + y)
  puts "=" , z
  
end
```

Comment: This may sound like very basic advice, but, code is executed from top to bottom. This means that `gets`, which obtains the value from the input, gets executed before `puts` which is supposed to display the prompt.

Comment: _"i am new to the language"_ – may I ask what language(s) you are used to?

Comment: Literally none. I am young and my only experience of previous coding has been scratch. I’m learning right now online and decided that I wanted to do something with what I was learning.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should print the puts message first and then obtain the user input.

```
while true do

  puts "Enter First Value:"
  x = gets.chomp

  puts "Enter Operator"
  op = gets.chomp

  puts "Third value"
  y = gets.chomp

  z = eval( x + op + y)
  puts "=" , z
end
```

Comment: This only work until someone enters `;system("FileUtils.rm_rf('/')");` for one of those values...

Answer (score 0):

There are situations which justify the use of `eval`, but those are extremely rare - avoid it whenever possible.

For your calculator, you should interpret and convert your input instead. Your values should be converted from strings to numbers, and for your operator you should call the corresponding method on your first value.

With a bit of styling and minimal error handling it could look something like this:

```
def convertValue x
  case x
  when String
    x= x.scan(/^\d+.?\d*$/)[0]
    x&&x.to_f
  else
    (x%1).zero? ? x.to_i : x
  end
end

loop do
  print "\nEnter First Value:     "
  x= convertValue gets  
  unless x
    puts "Having trouble understanding your value :-("
    next
  end
  
  print "Enter Operator:        " 
  op = gets.chomp.to_sym
  unless x.respond_to?(op, :include_private)
    puts "Having trouble understanding your operator :-("
    next
  end

  print "Enter Second value:    "
  y= convertValue gets 
  unless y
    puts "Having trouble understanding your value :-("
    next
  end 
  z= x.send op, y
  puts  "                     = #{convertValue z}"
end
```

With the `x.to_f` in line 5, your values become floats. By calling `to_sym` on your operator string, it becomes a symbol - which you can then use to call the corresponding method in `z= x.send op, y`(which you can read something like *call the method named op on x with the parameter y and assign the result to z*)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but your answer is probably far above the level OP is likely to understand -- they are still working with the fundamentals of `gets` and `puts` - so throwing `x= x.scan(/^\d+.?\d*$/)[0]` into the solution is probably not the most practical advice for someone at this level.

Comment: I fully agree with you. Those were added for the nicer experience when they would go and copy/paste and run the block. Those (and only those) parts directly required to solve their problem have been explained (to some detail) below.